# replace number on input number if it is too high directive

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, input, numbers

I would like that within an input if a user enters a year in addition to the current one, the numbers are replaced. 
example: the user enters 2020, I would like a directive that replaces 2020 with the current year (2018).

my html code:

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>year</ion-label>
  <ion-input type="number" [(ngModel)]="libro.year" name="data"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: Use a reactive form for this. Then you can have custom validators for formFields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a  `directive`  for DOM manipulation.
A directive gets a DOM element it's "attached" to and enhances it with some kind of features.
Use `Pipe`  to manipulate data.
A `pipe` gets data as an input, transforms it and outputs this data in another way.

So it's a perfect use case for  [`Pipe`](https://angular.io/guide/pipes)

```
<ion-item>
      <ion-label>Anno</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="number" [ngModel]="libro.year|replace" (ngModelChange)="setYear($event)" name="data"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
</ion-content>
```

**Pipe**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'replace'
})
export class ReplacePipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any): any {
      if(parseInt(value)>2018)
        return '2018';
         return value;
  }

}
```

**page.ts**

```
setYear(event)
{
  this.year.libro=event;
}
```

**[`LIVEDEMO`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-gxtgqi)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

In your component.ts

```
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

public form: FormGroup;

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { 
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      year: [2018, Validators.required],
    }, {validator: this.validateField('year')});
}

private validateField(controllerName: string) {
    return (group: FormGroup) => {
      const nameFiled = group.controls[controllerName];
      if (nameFiled.value > new Date().getFullYear()) {
        nameFiled.setValue(new Date().getFullYear());
        return nameFiled.setErrors({invalidYear: true});
      } else {
        return nameFiled.setErrors(null);
      }
    };
}
```

In your template.

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Anno</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="number" formControlName="year" name="data"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
</form>
```

I created a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-date-form) for this. Look at the Home page.